# Example of using react-hook-form with a Date/Time Picker and using Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datetimepicker, react-hook-form

Does anyone have an example of using react-hook-form with a Date/Time Picker and using Material-UI? I have been able to implement with a Mui TextField that has a type of "datetime-local", and I can set the Date/Time, but I have been unable to get a timestamp to appear in the field upon entering the form using default values for react-hook-form; that is, the date/time value doesn't appear in the picker. Upon manually setting the date/time value and submitting the form, the value is getting properly bound to the react-hook-form "data" object. Some fragments from my code are below.  I have replaced irrelevant code with ellipses (...).

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
...

interface IMyFormProps {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  occurrenceTimestamp: Date;
}

...

const MyForm: React.FC<IMyFormProps> = (props: IMyFormProps) => {

  ...

  // set up details for ReactHookForm
  const { register, control, formState, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      name: props.name,
      description: props.description,
      occurrenceTimestamp: props.occurrenceTimestamp
    },
    mode: "all"
  });

  ...

  return (
    <form onSubmit=... 
        // a text input for Name
        <TextField
          inputRef={register({ required: true })}
          name="name"
          label="Name"
          ...
        />

        // a text input for Description
        <TextField
          inputRef={register({ required: true })}
          name="description"
          label="Description"
          ...
        />

        // The Date/Time Picker
        <Controller
          render={(props) =>
            <TextField
              {...props}
              type="datetime-local"
              label="Occurrence Date/Time"
            />
          }
          name="occurrenceTimestamp"
          control={control}
        >
        </Controller>

    >
    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hello @thomas could you please paste under controller code? here

Answer (score 0):

```
Could you please try below code? 







    import React from 'react';
    import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
    import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
    ...

    interface IMyFormProps {
      name: string;
      description: string;
      occurrenceTimestamp: Date;
    }

    ...

    const MyForm: React.FC<IMyFormProps> = (props: IMyFormProps) => {

      ...

      // set up details for ReactHookForm
      const { register, control, formState, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
          name: props.name,
          description: props.description,
          occurrenceTimestamp: props.occurrenceTimestamp
        },
        mode: "all"
      });

      ...

      return (
        <form onSubmit=... 
            // a text input for Name
            <TextField
              inputRef={register({ required: true })}
              name="name"
              label="Name"
              ...
            />

            // a text input for Description
            <TextField
              inputRef={register({ required: true })}
              name="description"
              label="Description"
              ...
            />

     

>    // The Date/Time Picker
>         <Controller
>           render={(props) =>
>             <TextField
>               {...props}
>               type="datetime-local"
>               label="Occurrence Date/Time"
>             />
>           }
>           name="occurrenceTimestamp"
>           control={control}
>         >
>         </Controller>
> 
        >
        

</form>
      )
    }





> You can use below methods for getting value 
 <Col>
            <DatePicker
              name="datetime"
              className={"form-control"}
              selected={startDate}
              **onChange**={date => setStartDate(date)}
              showTimeSelect
              timeFormat="HH:mm"
              timeIntervals={15}
              timeCaption="time"
              dateFormat="MM-dd-yyyy h:mm"
            />
          </Col>

and setStartDate(date) 

Good luck and welcome to StackOverflow
```

Comment: Thanks, @Bipil, for your response! The suggestion that you posted appears to address the issue of setting a value for a date, which is already working in my code through the use of react-hook-form (onChange handling is built into react-hook-form). The challenge I'm facing is that the date is not displayed in the Date/Time Picker when entering the component with the form and a (default) value is set into the react-hook-form default values structure. (Note: The text fields are working fine.)